Record itinerary of a robot with ros2 bag and replay it
I am trying to evaluate a slam algorithm and for that, I want to create several maps of my environment with the same itinerary of the robot. To do that I have tried:

I recorded the topic /odom alone, when I replay the bag the robot doesn't move.
I recorded the topic /cmd_vel alone, when I replay the bag the robot moves but doesn't follow the exact same itinerary.
I recorded both topics /cmd_vel and /odom, when I replay the bag the robot moves but it doesn't follow the exact same itinerary.
I recorded both topics /odom and /cmd_vel,  when I replay the bag the robot doesn't move.

Did someone know how to record and play a robot itinerary with ros2?
Best regards
